# How to create APIs that accept file in the request object using jersey?

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey

I'm creating apis that needs to accept a file and other informations which will be sent in a `createAppRequest`. What should I need to do to my apis to be able to let the user upload a file through the apis.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createApp(CreateAppRequest){

// save app to db

}
```

Request class:

```
public class CreateAppRequest{

  // Other fields like name, createDate

    @JsonProperty("file")
    @Property("file")
    private byte [] file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're using the latest jersey release (2.7).

First you need to enable the MultiPart support in Jersey by adding the following to your `pom.xml` (if you are using maven, if not add the dependency to your project the same way you have added jersey):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

MultiPart is a Jersey Feature (such as the Jackson feature for example) and this means you will have to register it with both your client (if you have one) and your server apps.
Client side example (optional):

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
  .build();
```

Server side example:

```
final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
  .packages("your.root.package.here")
  .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
```

Once you've done all of the above you can define your post method like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
public Response createApp(
  @DefaultValue("true") @FormDataParam("enabled") boolean enabled,
  @FormDataParam("data") FileData bean,
  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
  @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {

    // your code here
}
```

For more information and examples take a look at the official jersey docs - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#multipart

---

However if you find this whole procedure too complicated you can always put your file in the request body as `application/octet-stream` and then read it in your post method with a `MessageBodyReader<T>`. If you are not sure what all these mean, or how to use them, again, check the jersey docs :)